# I am having trouble with HTML Javascript inclusion

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the information that I obtain through a form via a submit button, do a little processing, and print it out onto the web page, preventing it from being submitted to a web server by including (return false).

Here is the code to the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SmithSellsStuff</title>

 </head>   



<body>
<a href="week1-1.html">I'm too cheap to buy something nice</a>

<script>

    var myData = {
        price: "4.25",
        taxRate: "0.07",
        shipRate: "0.02"
    };
    myData.calculateTotal = function()  {
        myData.name = document.getElementById("name");
        myData.date = document.getElementById("date");
        myData.numItems = document.getElementById("number of items");
        var itemTotal = myData.numItems * myData.price;
        var taxTotal = (myData.numItems * myData.price) * myData.taxRate;
        var shipTotal = (myData.numItems * myData.price) * myData.shipRate;
        document.writeln(itemTotal);
        document.writeln(taxTotal);
        document.writeln(shipTotal);

    };
</script>
 <form>
    </p>
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1"/>                </label>
    </p>
    <label>Delivery Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="date" tabindex="2"/></label>
    </p>
    <label>Number of items: <input type="number" name="number of items" id="number of items" tabindex="3"/></label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calculateTotal(); return false;"/>
</form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

On the first page, I have a simple form with a field for name, date, number of items total, and a submit button. One error I'm getting is in the onclick tag. It says '_kof_1' is defined but never used. I don't think it is allowing my calculateTotal function to call.

Comment: `myData.calculateTotal` is not the same as `calculateTotal`.

Comment: I would expect you have lots of errors while loading this page. Try change `myData.calculateTotal = function` by `var calculateTotal = function`

Comment: Okay! Great news! I am getting feedback now. It loads a page and shows null values. Now I have to find out why my values are not populating.

Comment: A submit button with *return false* doesn't make a lot of sense. If you don't want it to be a submit button, make it type button. The form will submit anyway if the user presses enter while one of the other input's is focused. So if you want the function to run when the form is submitted, put it on the form's submit handler (and return false to stop the forms submitting if you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the function was not declared in the global scope, but rather **as a property** of `myData`.

```
myData.calculateTotal = function()  {
```

To solve this, simply change the call to:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myData.calculateTotal(); return false;"/>
```

Furthermore, since you want to get the name, date, and number of items from the text fields, you have to get the `.value` property to get the contents of the input fields, like so:

```
myData.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
myData.date = document.getElementById("date").value;
myData.numItems = parseInt(document.getElementById("number of items").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="week1-1.html">I'm too cheap to buy something nice</a>

<script>

function calculateTotal()
{
 alert("hai");
 var price="4.25";
 var taxRate="0.07";
 var shipRate="0.02";
 var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var date = document.getElementById("date");
    var numItems = document.getElementById("number_of_items").value;
    alert(numItems);
    var itemTotal = numItems * price;
    var taxTotal = (numItems * price) * taxRate;
    var shipTotal = (numItems * price) * shipRate;
    document.writeln("Total Items:"+itemTotal+"\tTax :"+taxTotal+"\tshipTotal:"+shipTotal);
    
 
 }
    </script>
 <form>
    <p>
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1"/>                </label>
    </p>
    <label>Delivery Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="date" tabindex="2"/></label>
    <p>
    <label>Number of items: <input type="number" name="number_of_items" id="number_of_items" tabindex="10"/></label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calculateTotal()"/>
</form>
  </body>

</html>
```

alert is just for to know method is calling or not, Hope this will help you